# Convert SteamID to 32/64 bit SteamID Swift

Tags: ios, swift, steam

I have SteamID with format `STEAM_0:1:21643603`.

How can I translate it to:

- Steam32ID(Account ID) with format `43287207`;
- Steam64ID with format `76561198003552935`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Valve SteamID wiki](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamID)

```
// STEAM_X:Y:Z
func convertToSteam32ID(steamString: String) -> UInt64 {
    let array = steamString.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
    let Y = UInt64(array[1])!
    let Z = UInt64(array[2])!
    return (Z << 1) | Y
}

func convertToSteam64ID(accountID accountID: UInt64) -> UInt64 {
    let Universe: UInt64 = 1
    let AccountType: UInt64 = 1
    let Instance: UInt64 = 1
    return ((Universe << 56) | (AccountType << 52) | (Instance << 32) | accountID)
}

let steam32ID = convertToSteam32ID("STEAM_0:1:21643603")

let steam64ID = convertToSteam64ID(accountID: steam32ID)
```

[Source Gist](https://gist.github.com/TikhonovAlexander/76782079e36c09bee181)